# How to write test for static method with `out` parameter with Pose C#

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, pose

I want to write a test for static method with `Pose` nu-get package, but I can't understand how syntax should looks like. There is one example for mocking at the GitHub page, but it's only for void method with one parameter:

```
Shim consoleShim = Shim.Replace(() => Console.WriteLine(Is.A<string>())).With(
    delegate (string s) { Console.WriteLine("Hijacked: {0}", s); });
```

But I need to mock method: `static bool ImagesExistsInDirectory(string ruleId, out string advertise_path);` It is different from example, it has out parameter and returns bool value. I think it should looks something like this, but it has out parameter error and mismatched paramaters.

```
Shim shim = Shim.Replace<string>(
                () => FileOps.ImagesExistsInDirectory(Pose.Is.A<string>(), out Pose.Is.A<string>())
                ).With<string, string>(
                delegate (string a, string b) { StubForStaticImages(a, out b); });
```

Could somebody explain how it works, please?

Comment: Please clearify: Do you want to **test** a static method with `out` parameter or do you want to **mock** a static method with an `out`parameter? Both are totally different

Comment: I want to mock it, I don't care about value of out parameter. I just need to get `true` from this to use in other test.

Comment: @Nkosi As I mentioned in the question, there are two problems: 1) out param: with this it doesn't even compile. It seems, I totally wrong about syntax of out params in `Pose`. 2) If I change `ImagesExistsInDirectory` to not use out, it has "Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type because some of the return type in the block are not implicitly convertable to the delegate retun type" and "Cannot convert type `bool` to `string`"

Comment: @Nkosi, I'm sorry, I'll try to figure it out.

Comment: @Nick check provided answer.

Answer (score 1):

The first issue is with trying to use `out` with `Is.A<string>()`.

The second is because the delegate defined to handle the invocation does not match what is expected since defining a `delegate` in lambda can't have `out`.

I solved this by first creating a separate delegate that matches the subject to be mocked

```
delegate bool StubForStaticImages(string id, out string path);
```

and using that in defining the shim. The rest was just a matter of following the examples in the documentation.

For testing purposes I defined a fake subject

```
class FileOps {
    public static bool ImagesExistsInDirectory(string ruleId, out string advertise_path) {
        advertise_path = "test";
        return false;
    }
}
```

The following example behaves as expected when the test is exercised

```
[TestMethod]
public void Pose_Static_Shim_Demo_With_Out_Parameter() {
    //Arrange
    var path = Is.A<string>();

    var expectedResult = true;
    var expectedPath = "Hello World";
    var expectedId = "id";
    string actualId = null; ;

    StubForStaticImages stub = new StubForStaticImages((string a, out string b) => {
        b = expectedPath;
        actualId = a;
        return expectedResult;
    });

    Shim shim = Shim
        .Replace(() => FileOps.ImagesExistsInDirectory(Is.A<string>(), out path))
        .With(stub);

    //Act
    string actualPath = default(string);
    bool actualResult = default(bool);
    PoseContext.Isolate(() => {
        actualResult = FileOps.ImagesExistsInDirectory(expectedId, out actualPath);
    }, shim);

    //Assert - using FluentAssertions
    actualResult.Should().Be(expectedResult);   //true
    actualPath.Should().Be(expectedPath);       //Hello World
    actualId.Should().Be(expectedId);           //id
}
```

Note the above only demonstrates the functionality of the mocking framework itself. Make the necessary changes for your actual tests.